# Changing element position when resizing viewport with jQuery: not working on WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, viewport

I've done some hours of research on the topic but I haven't quite found what I was looking for. I'm building a portfolio website with WordPress, and one of the layout I had in mind was something like this,
[portfolio layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tz9bg.png)
which I successfully made using overlapping rows in Bootstrap.
I would like the columns to stack when the viewport is < 768px so that the rows are not blocking each other, so I wrote the script using jQuery.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
        var width = $(window).width();
        if (width < 768) {
            $(".col-sm-4.col-sm-offset-8.higher").removeClass("higher");
        }
        else {
            $(".col-sm-4.col-sm-offset-8").addClass("higher");
        }
    });
});
```

I've tested it on CodePen and it seems to be working fine: [demo](https://codepen.io/judysmilingeyes/pen/jaaWgN) but I am having a hard time making it work in [WordPress](http://judithleng.com/portfolio/test/). Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: In the demo you provided, jQuery is not defined. Be sure to add a script tag reference to the jQuery library. Also, there should be no need to enclose all the code inside the ready function, the window resize function can be on its own.

Comment: Hi @KalebAnderson thank you! Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I think I've linked jQuery to the demo in Settings > Javascript, and I thought it'd be equivalent to adding the script tag?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the WordPress version. But see my response below and let me know if that's what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure how you'd like the page to behave, but I believe I achieved the column stacking behavior [in the Code Pen I forked from yours.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wPPGRK)

I achieved this with Bootstrap CSS only, no JS required.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <p class="p1">R1C1</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <p class="p1">R2C2</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <p class="p1">R3C3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Bootstrap grid is laid out in 12 columns, so the number of columns used in each section should typically total 12. I separated each of the three sections into equal size sections designated by `col-sm-4`. Bootstrap manages the resizing event that occurs at 768 pixels.